# Extracting dictionary variable names in a python file using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need advice in attacking this problem, I am stumped and don't really know where to start. **I don't want the code i just need advice**

The question is as follows:

> use regular expressions to extract all of the variable names which get
>   assigned to dictionary or set literals from a Python program located
>   in the file code.py. Python variables match the regular expression \w+
>   in Python (see the documentation about \w). Dictionary and set
>   literals start with a open squiggly brace ({).
>
> For example, given this Python program:
>
> code.py
>
> ```
> # Here is a Python file.
> names = {}
> foo = []
> names[0] = 12
> christmas ={
>   'tree': 'green',
>   'candy cane': 'red and white'
> }
>
> def yes():
>   return "yes"
> ```
>
> your program should produce this output:
>
> ```
> names
> christmas
> ```
>
> The variable names should be printed out in the order that they appear in the file. The Python code will be syntactically valid, but not necessarily executable without error.

So I have this code.py consisting of the above code and my new file called program.py where I have to read the contents of code.py and output the variable names for all the dictionaries. That means if code.py is to change and a lot more dictionaries were added in it would still output all of them in order.

Explanations as to what does what would help greatly!

Comment: This is obviously a homework assignment. But either way - it's all about the regular expression you need to create. program.py will read in code.py (see the python function `open`), then will need to find things that look like dictionaries (the bits with `{}`). See the python `re` module docs.

Comment: i got it mostly working, when i print it now it will output. ('names',)
('christmas',) instead of just the pure output. is there a way of doing this differently so it just outputs 'names' and 'christmas'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(\w*)\s*=\s*{(?:.|\n)*?}
```

How

```
(\w*) #match the dict name (any alphanumeric character and _ ) and capture it
\s*=\s* #match '=' with any amount of space around it
{ # match '{' 
(?:.|\n)*? # match any dict defintion over couple of lines
} # match '}'
```

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gP5iH5/1)

Comment: Could you explain what each one does? like why is there a space after the =, im a bit confused with all these regex's. Thanks