# Python Regex reading dictionary variable name from another file

Tags: python, regex

I really dont know how to word this.
I am creating a program that reads through another py file called code.py, it will find all **VALID** dictionary variable names and print them, easy enough? But the code im trying to run through is extremely tricky, purposely put in examples to trick the regex. The test code for code.py is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e64e71aca6095e54b77) and my current code is:

```
  import re
    with open ("code.py", "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
        potato = re.findall(r' *(\w+)\W*{',data,re.M)
        for i in range(len(potato)):
          print(potato[i])
```

That regex doesnt work 100%, when used on the test code it will print variables that arent meant to be printed such as:

```
# z={} 
z="z={}"
print('your mother = {}')
```

The expected output for the test file is 
a0, a, b ,c d, e, etc all the way down to z, then it will be aa, ab , ac, ad, etc all the way down to aq

and anything  really labeled z in the test code shouldnt print. 
I realise that regex isn't amazing for doing this but i have to use regex and it can be done.

EDIT: Using the new regex (r'^ *(\w+)\W*{',data,re.M) the output fails on examples where there are variables assigned on one line such as,

```
d={
   };e={
        };
```

Comment: Other than "l should print but z shouldn't" you don't explain what is the expected output. Or in other words, what *is* a "valid dictionary name" ?

Comment: Well anything that would be assaigned to a dictionary, so if i do d = {} that would make d a dictionary in python. but if i did d = '{}' that would make it a string not a dictionary and thus not be valid.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978328/using-regex-to-ignore-invalid-syntax)?  ...[Multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976935/getting-regex-to-be-more-leniant) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963963/extracting-dictionary-variable-names-in-a-python-file-using-regex)?

Comment: I can't get a answer that i understand and people just instantly down vote because of my poor english. I am trying to understand regex a bit better but i just cant. One of the answers told me to just not use regex but i have to and the other one was me trying to understand how to start the problem, just asking for advice on what regex to start with.

Comment: Why do you 'have' to use a regex? Attempting python code parsing using a regex is likely to always struggle with some particular code layout or other - you need to use a proper parser, and as it happens there are some already built for you in the Python Standard Library - look under Python Language Services for the parser, ast or possibly the symtable module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> l should print but z shouldn't

```
potato = re.findall(r'^ *(\w+)\W*{',data,re.M)
```

This should fix it.

EDIT:

```
".*?(?<!\\)"|'.*?(?<!\\)'|\([^)(]*\)|#[^\n]*\n|[^\'\"\#(\w\n]*(\w+)[^\w]*?{
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gP5iH5/6

Comment: Hmm that fixes certain problems but then i still have the problem of assigning multiple dictionaries on the same line using ' ; '

Comment: Ok final problem, the only thing now is it will output even if it's in a string or if its a comment, that is: # z={} and z="z={}" or z="\\\\{}"

Comment: Gah it just doesnt agree with all of them :/, is there some way to say 'Find anything except #, " and ()' so that it will match anything that doesnt have that before the {

Comment: that seems to deselect the # but still prints the z after it.

Comment: Firstly it doesn't work properly(the first ' thinks you are opening a string and its trying to close it but cant find a match ), i put \'s in front of the [^\'\"\#(\w\n] so that it would run properly. There were quite a few that weren't meant to output you can see them all at https://regex101.com/r/gP5iH5/2 (dont want to clog up section) Pretty much anything that is z or a word shouldn't be matched

Comment: I feel like im wasting your time sorry about that, The output should be a0, a,b,c,d,e,f,g, etc. all the way through the z and then aa, ab,ac,ad,ae,af, etc all the way through to aq. currently with that it only outputs ao, c, d, e ,f (it skips a and b because they are multiline) If you look through the text, all the variables named z except for the one after y shouldn't be matched. so it should be a perfect alphabet with a0 at the start.

Comment: no it shouldnt, what you got so far is almost perfect!

Comment: Last thing i promise, how should i go about fixing things like  aj  = {';'};ak={   which only recognises aj not ak because they are on the same line? that's where its failing now, on control structures and one line functions

Comment: Absolutely beutiful, last thing, it is printing blank lines where the line is invalid, how do i print only the actual parts that match?

Comment: @NickAdams use if else :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse a Python file using a regular expression will usually be able to be fooled. I would suggest the following kind of approach. The `dis` library could be used to disassemble byte code from compiled source code. From this all of the dictionaries can be picked out.

So assuming a Python source file called `code.py`:

```
import code
source_module = code
source_py = "code.py"

import sys, dis, re
from contextlib import contextmanager
from StringIO import StringIO

@contextmanager
def captureStdOut(output):
    stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = output
    yield
    sys.stdout = stdout

with open(source_py) as f_source:
    source_code = f_source.read()
    byte_code = compile(source_code, source_py, "exec")
    output = StringIO()

with captureStdOut(output):
    dis.dis(byte_code)
    dis.dis(source_module)

disassembly = output.getvalue()
dictionaries = re.findall("(?:BUILD_MAP|STORE_MAP).*?(?:STORE_FAST|STORE_NAME).*?\((.*?)\)", disassembly, re.M+re.S)

print dictionaries
```

As `dis` prints to stdout, you need to redirect the output. A regular expression can then be used to spot all of the entries. I do this twice, once by compiling the source to get the globals and once by importing the module to get the functions. There is probably a better way to do this but it seems to work.